# 3 node are created in localhost hazelcast on port 5710,5711,5712,5713 (hazelcast version 3.1.3)

Tags: hazelcast

Hi I am currently using default configuration version and running spring+JPA+Hibernate+Hazelcast for 2nd level cache.
On one of my server multiple hazelcast nodes are created,below is my configuration

```
    <group>
            <name>user-dev</name>
            <password>user-dev-pass</password>
        </group>
         <property name="hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name">SERVER1_HAZELCAST</property>
        <management-center enabled="true">http://localhost:8080/mancenter-3.1.8</management-center>
        <network>
            <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5711</port>
            <outbound-ports>
                <!--
                Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
                0 or * means use system provided port.
                -->
                <ports>0</ports>
            </outbound-ports>
            <join>
                <multicast enabled="false">
                    <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                    <multicast-port>54320</multicast-port>
                </multicast>
                <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <interface>127.0.0.1:5710</interface>
                </tcp-ip>

            </join>
            <interfaces enabled="false">
                <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
            </interfaces>
            <ssl enabled="false" />
            <socket-interceptor enabled="false" />  

Below are the logs:
Members [4] {
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5710 this
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5711
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5712
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5713
}

16:37:25,555 INFO  [com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterService] (hz.WS-DBCacheInstance.cached.thread-7) [127.0.0.1]:5711 [user-dev] 

Members [4] {
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5710
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5711 this
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5712
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5713
}
```

can any one help me on this

Edited added code:--

```
@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfig {
    private static final String INSTANCE_NAME = "mycache";
    private static final String HAZELCAST_CONFIG_XML = "hazelcast.xml";

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.getHazelcastInstanceByName(INSTANCE_NAME);
        if (instance == null) {
            Config config = new ClasspathXmlConfig(HAZELCAST_CONFIG_XML);
            config.setInstanceName(INSTANCE_NAME);
            config.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "none");
            instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastCacheManager cacheManager(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? Maybe I missed it.

Comment: @noctarius why hazelcast create multiple nodes,I have 2 server on 1 server it works fine and creates only one node and on server 2 it creates 3 nodes so total 4 nodes are created,As per my understanding there has to be only 2 node  for 2 server,please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet on how you are starting the Hazelcast nodes? btw, you can run any number of nodes per server.

Comment: code added its just bean config in spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let me try to rephrase your question, and I hope I got it right. You want to use Hazelcast (plain) and Hazelcast Hibernate integration? Your Hibernate configuration and your self-created Hazelcast instance have to have the same name. alternatively you can configure the Hibernate integration to be a Hazelcast client to connect to your cluster.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-hibernate#setting-client-server-for-hibernate
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/Hazelcast.html#getHazelcastInstanceByName-java.lang.String-

Comment: no ,let me give an example:-I have 2 war files ,which spring+hibernate+hazelcast configuration.

Comment: no ,let me give an example:-I have 2 war files ,which spring+hibernate+hazelcast configuration.when i start only server 1 and server 2 is stopped it works fine and vice versa is true and I can see only 1 member node ,but when I run both they form 4 members,hence I am confuse.this is very old application hence configuration bit confusing for me.There is cache manger configured but in code instance name is different when hazelcast instance is called and configuration in JPA for hazelcast instance name is different  but it works fine when only 1 server is up

Comment: I think the problem was with hazelcast instance name..different name was used in cachemanager while fetching hazelcast instance.when keep same same name in all configurations it works fine. thanks for the help